# install phpunit using pear on rhel5, it shows install success, but when type "phpunit", it shows command not found

Tags: phpunit, pear

how can I handle this?

I check the dir /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit, there seems no execute file in it, only have some php file

although I add "/usr/share/pear/PHPUnit" to php.ini ,include_path, still no help

Answer (score 0):

Add the PEAR bin path to your `$PATH` variable. You can find it with

```
$ pear config-get bin_dir
```